# playing sounds on samsung smart tv

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I am developing a simple game for samsung smart tv. I want to play little sound files when certain things happened like ready, win, lose. I don't want to deal with flash players, player controls .. Is there a way to use javascript to trigger a play sound action with a predefined sound volume and i nwant to do this several times in my code.

Comment: HTML5 Audio tag, obvious `play` method. More advanced: preload it and don't start before required.

Comment: I didn't try it myself but i read somewhere that smart tv doesn't support audio tag of html5.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add player object (`SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER`) into your `<body>` tag:

```
<object id="pluginPlayer" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; opacity: 0.0" classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER"></object>
```

And then in the app's javascript just use this function:

```
var playerObj = document.getElementById('pluginPlayer');
playerObj.Play("absolute_url_to_your_mp3");
```

As Player plugin executes in different location inside Samsung's filesystem you need always use absolute path to the file. It can be remote one, but you can use `location.href` of you app's `index.html` to get absolute local path of app's working directory where you can put the mp3s.

Check the documentation, here:

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/Device_API/Player

Answer (score 5):

this was my solution:

add to  of **index.html** file

```
<body>
    <object id="pluginPlayer" border=0    classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER">
...
...
...
</body>
```

inside my .js file **Scene1.js**

```
SceneScene1.prototype.initialize = function () {
var Player = document.getElementById('pluginPlayer');
var retVal=Player.Play("http://mysite.com/android/smartTV/little_wing.mp3");
...
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the SDK version 5.1 for TVs 2013 and 2014 model years and I have the following code works:

```
<object id="pluginPlayer" classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER"></object>

var playerObj = document.getElementById('pluginPlayer');
var fileName = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
playerObj.Play(document.location.href.split(fileName)[0] + 'test.mp3');
```

And this alternative also works (using Flash):

```
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:-1;">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100" height="50" id="fplayer">
        <param name="movie" value="test.swf"/>
        <param name="quality" value="high"/>
        <param name="bgcolor" value="blue"/>
    </object>
</div>
```

And many thanks to Dobiatowski!