# Playing AAC, MP3 on Samsung SmartTV or LG Netcast

Tags: flash, html, rtmp, samsung-smart-tv, television

Do you know if there is any possibility to play the AAC or MP3 (or even WMA or OGG) icecast radio streams on Samsung SmartTV or LG NetCast platform? Ideally in HTML with use of either HTML component or Samsung/LG built-in player or even embedded Flash player?

In the case it is not possible with any of above formats, we can still use the flv/rtmp, which I guess should work nicely in embeded flash player on TV, isn't it?

Anyway our preference is icecast AAC/MP3.

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is doable.

Recently I've post answer for similar question, so go and check it:
[playing sounds on samsung smart tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006593/playing-sounds-on-samsung-smart-tv/10138625#10138625)

And here is direct link to the docs:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Technical_Notes/Player/Detailed_player_specification